# How to order a generic list by date vb.net

Tags: vb.net, list, generics

One of the fields of my generic list is "date".

how can I order the list by this field?

Comment: `newList = myGenericList.OrderBy(Function (d) d.Date).ToList()`

Comment: can't find "OrderBy" in the list of methods in vb.net

Comment: Perhaps you could add some code so we can see if it really is a List, really is a generic and what it really contains.  Lists per se do not have fields, so please clarify.

Comment: It works, i need to import Linq statement. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you looking for it:
    myList= myList.OrderBy(function(i) i.date).ToList();